# Installing forefront identity manager 2010, need a guide/tutorial

Tags: microsoft-forefront

Im trying to install forefront identity manager 2010 (FIM) in my test environment. Since I never done it before I need somekind of help how to do it. I've been trying to find a guide or a video that could help me, but unfortunately i haven't found anything yet. I know that technet have it's own guide but i think it's a little bit advanced for a beginner.

Comment: We don't do tutorials here.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to go is to spend a few days taking the RampUp course for configuring it. There is a lot of information on getting started http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/399.forefront-identity-manager-resources-en-us.aspx#Getting_Started

i think the virtual machines and step by step guidance from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/forefront/ff793470.aspx is pretty good.